# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'search_nodes' - Python

Tags: python, csv, attributeerror

I've built a tree using ete2 package. Now I'm trying to write a piece of code that takes the data from the tree and a csv file and does some data analysis through the function `fre`.
Here is an example of the csv file I've used:

```
PID Code    Value 
1    A1...   6
1    A2...   5
2    A....   4
2    D....   1
2    A1...   2
3    D....   5
3    D1...   3
3    D2...   5
```

Here is a simplified version of the code

```
from ete2 import Tree
import pandas as pd
t= Tree("((A1...,A2...)A...., (D1..., D2...)D....).....;", format=1)
data= pd.read_csv('/data_2.csv', names=['PID','Code', 'Value'])
code_count = data.groupby('Code').sum()
total_patients= len(list (set(data['PID'])))
del code_count['PID']

############

def fre(code1,code2):
    code1_ancestors=[]
    code2_ancestors=[]
    for i in t.search_nodes(name=code1)[0].get_ancestors():
        code1_ancestors.append(i.name)
    for i in t.search_nodes(name=code2)[0].get_ancestors():
        code2_ancestors.append(i.name)
    common_ancestors = []
    for i in code1_ancestors:
        for j in code2_ancestors:
            if i==j:
                common_ancestors.append(i)
    print common_ancestors

####

for i in patients_list:
    a= list (data.Code[data.PID==patients_list[i-1]])
    #print a
    for j in patients_list:
        b= list (data.Code[data.PID==patients_list[j-1]])
        for k in a:
            for t in b:
                fre (k,t)
```

However, an error is raising which is:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-f9b47fcec010> in <module>()
     38         for k in a:
     39             for t in b:
---> 40                 fre (k,t)

<ipython-input-12-f9b47fcec010> in fre(code1, code2)
     12     code1_ancestors=[]
     13     code2_ancestors=[]
---> 14     for i in t.search_nodes(name=code1)[0].get_ancestors():
     15         code1_ancestors.append(i.name)
     16     for i in t.search_nodes(name=code2)[0].get_ancestors():

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'search_nodes'
```

I've tried to manually pass all possible values to the function and it works! However, When I'm using the last section of the code, it raises the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing your global variable 't' with your for loop.

If you print out its value before each call to your function, you will find that you have assigned it to a string at some point.